# Visual Studio for Mac can't run Android Emulator on Xamarin platform

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, emulation

I installed the latest updates on Visual Studio for Mac and download xCode 13.1 ..
Everything is fine with the project, but when I try to run the project I receive message `Execution failed` on the build page (above in the building field).

In the Build Output console I receive this messages:

```
Building MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android (Debug)
Build started 11/24/2021 10:15:58 PM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target XamlG:
  Skipping target "XamlG" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CssG:
  Skipping target "CssG" because it has no outputs.
Target CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo:
  Skipping target "CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CssG:
  Skipping target "CssG" because it has no outputs.
Target CoreCompile:
  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target XamlC:
  Skipping target "XamlC" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    MaritsaTundzhaForecast -> /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.dll
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target _ResolveAndroidTooling:
    Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
    Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
Target _ResolveXamarinAndroidTools:
     Found Xamarin.Android 12.0.0.3
Target _CheckInstantRunCondition:
    Dex Fast Deployment Enabled: False
Target _ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
    MonoAndroid Tools: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/
    Android Platform API level: 30
    TargetFrameworkVersion: v11.0
    Android NDK: 
    Android SDK: /Users/pizhev/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/
    Android SDK Build Tools: /Users/pizhev/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/30.0.2/
    Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home/
    Application Java class: android.app.Application
Target _CleanIntermediateIfNeeded:
    Target _CleanMonoAndroidIntermediateDir:
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/R.cs.flag".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/acw-map.txt".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/customview-map.txt".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/_javac.stamp".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/res.flag".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/android_debug_keystore.flag".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/adb.props".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/libraryimports.cache".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/static.flag".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/libraryprojectimports.cache".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/R.txt".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/buildid.txt".
        Deleting file "obj/Debug/resolvedassemblies.hash".
    Creating directory "obj/Debug/stamp/".
    Creating "obj/Debug/stamp/_CleanIntermediateIfNeeded.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target ProcessGoogleServicesJsonChecks:
    No GoogleServicesJson file specified.
Target _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj" is building "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

Target ResolveProjectReferences:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj" is building "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj" is building "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):

Target _ComputeAndroidResourcePaths:
    Creating directory "obj/Debug/res/".
Target _ResolveLibraryProjectImports:
    Creating "obj/Debug/stamp/_ResolveLibraryProjectImports.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _BuildLibraryImportsCache:
    Creating "obj/Debug/stamp/_BuildLibraryImportsCache.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _GenerateAndroidResourceDir:
    Creating "obj/Debug/res.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _GenerateLayoutBindings:
  Skipping target "_GenerateLayoutBindings" because it has no outputs.
Target _ConvertResourcesCases:
    Creating directory "obj/Debug/flata/".
    Creating directory "obj/Debug/flat/".
    Creating "obj/Debug/stamp/_ConvertResourcesCases.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _UpdateAndroidResgen:
    Creating "obj/Debug/R.cs.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target XamlG:
  Skipping target "XamlG" because it has no outputs.
Target CssG:
  Skipping target "CssG" because it has no outputs.
Target CssG:
  Skipping target "CssG" because it has no outputs.
Target XamlG:
  Skipping target "XamlG" because it has no outputs.
Target CoreCompile:
  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
    Touching "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/obj/Debug/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj.CopyComplete".
Target GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems:
    Target _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromTransitiveProjectReferences:
        __________________________________________________
        Project "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj" is building "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android -> /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/bin/Debug/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.dll
Target _ResolveAssemblies:
      Adding assembly reference for MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for netstandard, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Data.DataSetExtensions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Drawing.Common, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.ComponentModel.Composition, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Transactions, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.Web.Services, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Net.Http, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime.Serialization, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for System.ServiceModel.Internals, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for FormsViewGroup, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Java.Interop, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for MaritsaTundzhaForecast, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Mono.Android, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for mscorlib, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for MySqlConnector, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Newtonsoft.Json, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Core, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Data, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System, recursively...
        Adding assembly reference for Mono.Security, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Numerics, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Numerics.Vectors, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Runtime, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Xml, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for System.Xml.Linq, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.Experimental, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Runtime, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.AsyncLayoutInflater, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Core, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.CursorAdapter, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.DocumentFile, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Interpolator, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.UI, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.Utils, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModelSavedState, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Media, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.MultiDex, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Print, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.SlidingPaneLayout, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.Transition, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable.Animated, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.VersionedParcelable, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Essentials, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Core, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Maps, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Platform, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Google.Android.Material, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps, recursively...
      Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks, recursively...
Target _CreatePackageWorkspace:
    Creating directory "obj/Debug/android/assets/".
Target _CopyConfigFiles:
  Skipping target "_CopyConfigFiles" because it has no inputs.
Target _ConvertPdbFiles:
  Skipping target "_ConvertPdbFiles" because it has no outputs.
Target _GenerateJavaStubs:
    Creating "obj/Debug/stamp/_GenerateJavaStubs.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _ManifestMerger:
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/manifestmerger.jar com.xamarin.manifestmerger.Main obj/Debug/android/manifestmerger.rsp 
Target _ConvertCustomView:
    Creating "obj/Debug/stamp/_ConvertCustomView.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _AddStaticResources:
    Creating directory "obj/Debug/android/bin".
    Copying file from "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v11.0/mono.android.jar" to "/Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/obj/Debug/android/bin/mono.android.jar".
    Touching "obj/Debug/android/bin/mono.android.jar".
    Creating "obj/Debug/static.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _GeneratePackageManagerJava:
    Creating "obj/Debug/stamp/_GeneratePackageManagerJava.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _FixupCustomViewsForAapt2:
    Touching "obj/Debug/R.cs.flag".
Target _GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
  Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because it has no outputs.
Target _CreateBaseApk:
    Touching "obj/Debug/android/bin/packaged_resources".
Target _CompileJava:
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 "@/var/folders/n4/97jdxsf51ml4mffg4mqxqsq00000gn/T/tmp28a8a729.tmp" -target 1.8 -source 1.8 
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    Creating "obj/Debug/_javac.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _CompileToDalvik:
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx1G -classpath /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/r8.jar com.android.tools.r8.D8 --debug --min-api 21 --output obj/Debug/android/bin/ --lib /Users/pizhev/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-30/android.jar --lib /Users/pizhev/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-30/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar obj/Debug/android/bin/classes.zip /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v11.0/mono.android.jar /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/java_runtime_fastdev.jar /Users/pizhev/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.annotation/1.1.0.8/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/../../jar/androidx.annotation.annotation.jar /Users/pizhev/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection/1.1.0.6/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection.jar /Users/pizhev/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.lifecycle.common/2.2.0.4/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/../../jar/androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common.jar /Users/pizhev/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.arch.core.common/2.1.0.7/buildTransitive/monoandroid90/../../jar/androidx.arch.core.core-common.jar /Users/pizhev/.nuget/packages/xamarin.google.guava.listenablefuture/1.0.0.2/buildTransitive/monoandroid50/guava-listenablefuture.jar obj/Debug/lp/61/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/95/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/59/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/92/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/66/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/68/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/57/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/69/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/56/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/58/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/67/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/93/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/94/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/60/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/0/jl/formsviewgroup.jar obj/Debug/lp/89/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/73/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/87/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/80/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/74/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/75/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/81/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/86/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/72/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/88/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/65/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/62/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/96/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/54/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/55/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/63/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/64/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/90/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/79/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/83/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/77/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/70/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/84/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/85/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/71/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/76/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/82/jl/classes.jar obj/Debug/lp/78/jl/classes.jar 
    Warning in obj/Debug/lp/92/jl/classes.jar:androidx/browser/trusted/ConnectionHolder.class:
      Type `androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `Landroidx/browser/trusted/ConnectionHolder;getServiceWrapper()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;`
    Warning in obj/Debug/lp/92/jl/classes.jar:androidx/browser/browseractions/BrowserServiceFileProvider.class:
      Type `androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `Landroidx/browser/browseractions/BrowserServiceFileProvider;saveBitmap(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroidx/concurrent/futures/ResolvableFuture;`
    Warning in synthesized for lambda desugaring:
      Type `androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Resolver` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `androidx.browser.trusted.-$$Lambda$ConnectionHolder$Rp3Hxy1AUk9cWatAvfzHyT3B2KI`
    Creating "obj/Debug/stamp/_CompileToDalvik.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:26.74

========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Build successful.
```

I don't know what happened here but I think everything looks fine ?

In the package console I receive this messages:

```
    Getting restore information for project /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.iOS/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.iOS.csproj
Getting restore information for project /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj
Running non-parallel restore.
Reading project file /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj.
The restore inputs for 'MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android' have changed. Continuing restore.
Restoring packages for /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj...
Restoring packages for MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0...
Resolving conflicts for MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0...
Checking compatibility of packages on MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android 1.0.0 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for MySqlConnector 1.3.9 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.Essentials 1.6.1 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.Forms.Maps 5.0.0.2012 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for MaritsaTundzhaForecast 1.0.0 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser 1.3.0 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData 2.2.0.4 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.2.1.1 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4 1.0.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 117.0.0 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture 1.0.0.2 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Common 2.1.0.7 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Runtime 2.1.0.7 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core 2.2.0.4 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.Experimental 1.0.0.8 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation 1.1.0.8 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat 1.2.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView 1.0.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout 1.1.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Core 1.3.2.1 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment 1.2.5.4 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime 2.2.0.4 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView 1.1.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Transition 1.3.1.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable 1.1.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2 1.0.0.8 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.UI 1.0.0.7 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.Utils 1.0.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Media 1.2.1.1 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 117.1.0 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 117.1.0 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.Build.Download 0.10.0 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common 2.2.0.4 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration 1.0.8 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources 1.2.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.CursorAdapter 1.0.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout 1.1.1.1 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection 1.1.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView 1.1.0.4 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.VersionedParcelable 1.1.1.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity 1.1.0.5 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Checking compatibility for Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModelSavedState 2.2.0.4 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable.Animated 1.1.0.6 with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
All packages and projects are compatible with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Committing restore...
Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/obj/project.assets.json
Writing cache file to disk. Path: /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/obj/project.nuget.cache
Persisting dg to /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/obj/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
Restored /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.Android.csproj (in 434 ms).
Reading project file /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast/MaritsaTundzhaForecast.csproj.
All packages and projects are compatible with .NETStandard,Version=v2.0.
Committing restore...
Writing assets file to disk. Path: /Users/pizhev/Projects/Arda Forecast/BackUp Android/MaritsaTundzhaForecast/obj/project.assets.json

NuGet Config files used:
    /Users/pizhev/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Packages successfully restored
```

So Now I installed the last SDK's and last Visual Studio Updates.. When I connect with cable Visual Studio with my Android phone everything is fine.. But I need the emulator for testing ..
Can I get information how to fix this problem ?

This is my Android SDK Manager:

[image: SDK MANAGER Platforms]

[image: SDK MANAGER TOOLS]

[image: SDK MANAGER LOCATIONS]

This is my SDK Installed versions..

[image: SDK Installed Versions]

Comment: the Android emulator is part of the Android SDK and tools and not directly related to Xamarin.  I don't see any error messages in what you posted that have to do with the emulator.  There should be a separate window with deployment messages.  Have you run the SDK manager to verify you have all the appropriate toolsets and updates installed?

Comment: I update the question and take a screenshot of my sdk manager on Visual Studio.. I think everything is fine... Do you know what can I do to see where is the problem exactly ?

Comment: @BlagovestPizhev You need to check the requirements first in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=macos&pivots=macos And then try to set a emulator with the steps in the link i provided.

Comment: Try start the emulator from command-line and see what errors you get